# How to install Torchlight from GamersGate on Ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, games

I know it's easiest on Steam but I got the game from GamersGate which lets you download the game with their own installer. I'm asking about this game specifically because I know it runs on Linux. Is there a way to install it on (X)ubuntu?

Comment: Did you get a linux version? What format did it come in? iso, archive?

Comment: No I bought it on GamersGate which use their own Windows installer.

Comment: Then it is not for linux, you must use wine, here is an winehq page for it, it says it will work well https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10540